# A framework for modeling tasks, behaviors and characteristics

Tags: performance, io-psychology

I'm doing my master's thesis on evaluating startup team dynamics from an investors's perspective. To construct and argue the methods that I'm suggesting, I'd like to build a simple model of most important startup tasks, behaviors and characteristics where a certain characteristic of the team, say "mutual trust" would be connected to a desired behavior, like "suggesting ideas" that would be connected to success in a certain important task, like "pivoting the business idea". Any characteristic could be connected to multiple behaviors, and behaviors could be connected to multiple tasks. So the model could look something like this:

[image: The framework concept]

**Are there any similar models/frameworks being used in scientific context?** To me, this seems like an intuitive way to build suggested connections between team/individual characteristics and business success, but I fail to find anything like this. Note that while I'm interested in team characteristics, similar logic on individual level will do fine as well.

Please note that I don't intend to build a comprehensive map of all tasks, or do hypothesis-testing on each individual connection, but rather use this map as a basis for suggesting practical methods that will be tested.

Comment: Normally the framework concept in social psychology is not worked in that way, if you must work with the concept of framework could study variables of social psychology in relation to the network, focusing on the group, on the other hand if what interests you is the performance might study what characteristics of the group or profiles or mix of profiles increase it.